# using existing SqlCe database in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have a SqlCe database which i made for another project. Now i want to use it for a windows phone project. My database structure is

[image]

I copied my database into my project folder and set it's build action as "content" and copy to output directory as "copy always".
In my main page i used this:

```
 private const string Con_String = @"isostore:/mydb.sdf";
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        using (mTableDatabaseContext context = new mTableDatabaseContext(Con_String))
        {
            if (!context.DatabaseExists())
            {
                context.CreateDatabase();
            }

            if (!iso.FileExists("mydb.sdf"))
            {
                MoveReferenceDatabase();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void MoveReferenceDatabase()
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("mydb.sdf", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile("mydb.sdf"))
            {
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and my mTableDatabaseContext class is like that:

```
 public class mTableDatabaseContext:DataContext
{

    public mTableDatabaseContext(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
    {

    }


    public Table<dic> my_dics
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<dic>();
        }
    }


    public Table<learn_table> my_learn_tables
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<learn_table>();
        }
    }

}
```

But i cant use my database and copy of my database cant be performed???
What can i do to do this??
How can i do this?? Can anyone help me??

Comment: follow this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688925/using-existing-sqlce-database-in-windows-phone

Comment: That's my question !!!@PradeepKesharwani

Comment: i copied above url by mistake see this one see this onehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688925/using-existing-sqlce-database-in-windows-phone

Comment: See my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
private const string Con_String = @"Data Source=isostore:/mydb.sdf";
```

instead of

`private const string Con_String = @"isostore:/mydb.sdf";`